# PHP not starting session?

Tags: php, mysql, session

I have written a simplte PHP login script which starts a session:

```
//Lets start our session
//Create our session
$_SESSION['token'] = md5($user['salt'].$user['user_id'].$user['username']);
$_SESSION['id'] = $user['user_id'];
$_SESSION['username'] = $user['username'];
header('Location: index.php');
die();
```

And on the index file I have this code:

```
if(array_key_exists('id', $_SESSION) && array_key_exists('username', $_SESSION)):
    echo 'Welcome user';
else:
    include 'login.php';
endif;
```

Everytime the user logs in it doesn't start a session. I made sure the password and usename is on the database (using my own validation script).  Can anyone see anything I am missing.

Thanks

Peter

Comment: where is your session_start()?

Comment: Are you doing a 
 session_start();

Comment: where do you start the session?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You missed the most important part of starting a session:  `session_start()`

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['token'] = md5($user['salt'].$user['user_id'].$user['username']);
$_SESSION['id'] = $user['user_id'];
$_SESSION['username'] = $user['username'];
header('Location: index.php');
die();
```

And on the index page as well:

```
session_start();
if(array_key_exists('id', $_SESSION) && array_key_exists('username', $_SESSION)):
    echo 'Welcome user';
else:
    include 'login.php';
endif;
```

Comment: Crap!! Of course,  this is why I should code and drink beer a 2am! I can't belive I forgot the session_start(); function! Thanks mate :)

Comment: it happens many times with me normally i start session in header file but in some files there's no need to include header so i also did same mistake lol :D

Answer (score 5):

Add `session_start();` on the top of all files where you are using sessions.

Comment: Crap!! Of course,  this is why I should code and drink beer a 2am! I can't belive I forgot the session_start(); function! Thanks mate :)

Answer (score 1):

do you have your session_start(); somewhere?  i don't see it in your code sample.